# Fluffy French Toast

Tags: baking

What is the best kind of bread to use for french toast if you want it to be fluffy? I like using Brioche bread, but it isn't very fluffy! should I use the bread they use to make Texas Toast?

Comment: You might try challah, which is similar to brioche but without the butter.

Answer (score 3):

There's 2 aspects about making fluffy french toast:

1. Bread: Fluffy french toast comes from fluffy bread. Dense breads like brioche and many whole wheats and sourdoughs aren't going to be light no matter what you do. You need a lighter, fluffier bread, a lot of times mass marketed non-artisan breads are the way to go
2. Dipping: fluffy bread is full of air, and air will get filled up with an egg-milk mix, making your french toast soggy or too eggy. The secret is to use a slightly runny pancake batter rather than a pure egg-milk mix as this keeps the bread from absorbing too much moisture